# Jenkinsfile not executing entire shell script

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following in a Jenkinsfile as a discrete stage:

```
        stage("Check if Postman scripts are already cloned, delete") {
            steps {
                sh "[ -d postman-scripts ] && rm -rf postman-scripts && echo 'Directory cleared.'"
            }
        }
```

However when I look at my Jenkins pipeline it looks like it fails and doesn't run the entire script:

```
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Check if Postman scripts are already cloned, delete)
[Pipeline] sh
+ '[' -d postman-scripts ']'
[Pipeline] }
```

Is that because it's not finding the `postman-scripts` directory, so it's not executing the rest of the script? And is that being counted as a build failure? It skips all following stages, so logically I think it's doing that.

Also any help with the bash scripting would be nice, I'm not entirely sure how I can string this all together on one line to do what I want (IF directory exists, remove directory. Otherwise do nothing).

Comment: You can just `rm -rf postman-scripts`. Checking to see if it exists first doesn't seem to have much purpose.

Comment: wow you're right. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your shell test condition `[ -d postman-scripts ]` will FAIL if the directory does not exist. That is a failure like any other command, so it exits. @jordanm is correct, using `-f` will return  success even if nothing exists to remove, so your next step will continue. Exception if unable to remove files because of a system lock or similar, which is probably a good thing,